# Common function is not being called from listeners in ext js

Tags: extjs, focus, dropdown

I am trying to call '`ControlFocus`' method from drop down `focus` event but it gives me error. I know it is some scoping issue but not sure how to do it.

So basically structure is as follow:

```
 Ext.define('Panel', {
 extend: 'Ext.Panel.panel',
   
    items: [       
        {
            xtype: 'container', 
            items: []
        },
        {
            xtype: 'fieldcontainer', 
            itemId: 'namefields',          
            items[]  
        },
        {
            xtype: 'fieldcontainer',
            itemId: 'namefieldsRow2',          
            items: []
        },
    
    ],

controlFocus: function(field) {  
     // I want to use this function in several controls
} 
});
```

Actual code

```
Ext.define('Panel', {
    extend: 'Ext.Panel.panel',
   
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'hiddenfield',
            name: 'ID',
            itemId: 'id',
            value: 0
        },
        {
            xtype: 'container',          
            style: 'padding: 18px 0 10px 0;',
            defaults: {
                padding: '0 10 0 0',
                style: 'padding-left: 0;'
            },
            items: [
                {
                    name: 'ExportCode',
                    xtype: 'hiddenfield'
                },
                {
                    fieldLabel: 'BusinessStructure'),
                    name: 'BusinessStructureId',
                    itemId: 'BusinessStructureId',
                    lookupName: 'Structure',
                    xtype: 'combo',
                    id: 'BusinessStructureId',                                     
                    listeners: {                           
                        change: function(field) {                                                   
                        },

                        focus:function(combo, e, opts){                           
                        },
                        // scope: this,     // not working
                        blur: function(field,ev) {                                                  
                           
                        },                          
                    },                        
                },
                {
                    fieldLabel: 'ClientType',
                    name: 'ClientTypeId',
                    itemId: 'ClientTypeId',
                    lookupName: 'ClientType',
                    xtype: 'combo',                   
                },              
            ]
        },
        {
            xtype: 'fieldcontainer',
            itemId: 'namefields',
            layout: 'hbox',
            fieldDefaults: {
                labelCls: 'h-bold'
            },
            cls: 'u-hr-bottom-light',
            items: [
                {
                    fieldLabel:'Name'),
                    labelClsExtra: 'x-form-item-label x-required',
                    name: 'Name',
                    itemId: 'Name',
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    fieldCls: 'big',
                    width: 650,
                    listeners: { 
                        focus: function(field, ev) {    
                        },
                        blur: function(field,ev) {  
                        },                  
                    }             
                },                   
                {
                    fieldLabel: 'FirstName'),
                    labelClsExtra: 'x-form-item-label x-required',
                    name: 'FirstName',
                    itemId: 'FirstName',
                    xtype: 'textfield',      
                    listeners: { 
                        focus: function(field) {
                        },
                        blur: function(field, ev) {  
                        },                                                  
                    }            
                },               
            ]
        },
        {
            xtype: 'fieldcontainer',
            itemId: 'namefieldsRow2',
            claims: [req.pm, req.au, req.autax],
            layout: 'hbox',
            fieldDefaults: {
                labelCls: 'h-bold'
            },
            cls: 'u-hr-bottom-light',
            items: [
                {
                    fieldLabel: 'ClientTitle',
                    name: 'Title',
                    itemId: 'Title',                  
                    xtype: 'editablecombo',                   
                },
                ]
        },
    
    ],

controlFocus: function(field) {  
     // I want to use this function in several controls
} 
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [focus](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.1/classic/Ext.form.field.ComboBox.html#event-focus) event gives you direct access to the combo.

You could just add the function directly to your listeners config like this:

```
listeners: {
    focus: function(combo, event, eOpts){ 
        //Add code here
    }
}
```

Since you don't want to add the function directly (You mentioned you wanted to use it in several components in your comment in the method) you should check out the [view controller](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.1/classic/Ext.app.ViewController.html).
That way you can use just a String reference for the function in the view controller.

Here is a working sencha fiddle example: [example](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3j6q)

EDIT:

Since you don't want to use MVVM:

Another solution would be to have a "global" class with statics like this:

```
    Ext.define('Global.class.Listeners', {
        extend: 'Ext.Base',
        statics: {
            controlFocus: function (field) {
                debugger;
                //do some work here
                // I want to use this function in several controls
                Ext.toast('Global static class');
            }
        }
    });
```

In that case you could add the listener like this:

```
                listeners: {
                    change: function (field) {},
                    
                    focus: Global.class.Listeners.controlFocus,

                    blur: function (field, ev) {
                        //blur logic
                    }
                }
```

I modified my sencha fiddle for you: [example](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3j6q)

Oh and btw:

Never overwrite the @cfg [id](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.1/classic/Ext.Component.html#cfg-id) -> Alway use the [itemId](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.1/classic/Ext.Component.html#cfg-itemId).
Otherwise you might run into duplicate errors!

Comment: Hi KaMun, thanks for sharing this, however my project doesn't user MVC so I can't create a controller

Comment: I updated my post with another solution

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried a simpler approach?

The [focus](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.form.field.ComboBox.html#event-focus) event of the combobox gives you a reference to the combobox that has launched it, so you can use the standard approach with the [listeners](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.form.field.ComboBox.html#cfg-listeners) config as below:

```
// Combobox
{       
    xtype: 'combo', 
    ...
    listeners: {
        focus: function(combo, e, opts){ 
            combo.up("panel").controlFocus(combo); 
        }
    }
}
```

Note! There is for sure a typo or missing/wrong brackets in the code you posted, so it is hard to know the scope of your controlFocus method (the container, the panel,...)

---EDIT---

Now that I got the code of your "Panel" I created a [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/3j7a) that shows how it works.

Comment: HI @v1rg11, it gives me index.js:660 Uncaught TypeError: a.up(...).controlFocus is not a function

Comment: As I said in my answer, there is something wrong with the syntax and formatting of the code you posted. Can you fix it please? From it I dont understand what component has the controlFocus method

Comment: I have updated the code

Comment: Thanks! With your Panel definition I created a simple [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/3j7a) to show how it works: when you focus/click on any field, it will call your function and show you a popup with the name of the field that lauched the event

Answer (score 0):

The error is thrown, because you did not specify the *scope* property in your listener configuration.
As stated in the docs, it defaults to the component firing the event, in your case the combo box,
see [docs](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.5.1/modern/Ext.Evented.html#method-addListener) for details.

Your solution should be:

```
// combobox
{       
    xtype: 'combo', 
     ...
    listeners: {
        focus: 'controlFocus',
        scope: this
    }
}
```

Comment: It still throws the same errors

Comment: Did a basic [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3j84)
There are some issues in your posted code, wrong or missing brackets, invalid extend declaration, bad formatting.
I recommend putting the event handling logic in a separate controller. For the example I've put the items in the constructor call to get the correct scope. Declarative approach did not seem to be working.